# Send accelerometer data from android to bluetooth crashing app

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have working code that sends SeekBar slider values to bluetooth and android.  I want to change it to read and send accelerometer values to bluetooth so I can control a robot by tilting phone.  Seekbar code works just fine.  I replaced this in the onCreate method.  "brightness" is the name of the seekbar because it is controlling an led for the time being.

```
brightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            try {
                btSocket.getOutputStream().write(String.valueOf(progress).getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {   }
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
    });
```

`with this as a separate method

```
    @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    int x = (int)((event.values[0]+9.8)*256/2/9.8);
    accelText.setText(" X = " + x);
    try {
        btSocket.getOutputStream().write(String.valueOf(x).getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
            msg("error at btSocket");
    }
}
```

and of course I have the proper declarations in the onCreate method:

```
    sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

compiles fine.  When it runs I get the "unfortunately app has stopped working" message.  When I comment out the btSocket line everything works (except for sending the message, obviously).  Anyone see what I am doing wrong.  Thanks so much - in advance.

Comment: What is the logcat output when the crash happens?

Comment: 03-23 15:13:37.158  17363-17363/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.blogspot.drcodd.robotcontrol.RobotControl.onSensorChanged(RobotControl.java:141)
03-23 15:13:37.178  17363-17363/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000043d3 (code=-6), thread 17363 (dd.robotcontrol)
03-23 15:13:37.278  26318-26318/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 17363, tid: 17363, name: dd.robotcontrol  >>> com.blogspot.drcodd.robotcontrol <<<
03-23 15:13:37.548    640-17552/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.blogspot.drcodd.robotcontrol/.RobotControl

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the permissions for BLUETOOTH in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Maybe you need this too

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

If you do so, what's the exception message?

Comment: This should be comment.

Comment: I can't do coments, i'm new.

Comment: yes, it has the permissions.  I Connect with bluetooth module and can control an led (arduino is involved) with on and off buttons and the seekbar that I referenced.  It is just the line "btSocket.getOutputStream..." in the onSensorChanged method that is causing the problem

Comment: You can try to unchain the write to see if the error is in the write part.